# Unusual delay in scheduling with TimerTask in java

Tags: java, timertask

I am scheduling a thread for daily run using TimerTask. Here is the code.

```
private void scheduleDailyProcess() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    int period = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //24 hours
    timer.schedule(new DailyProcess(), c.getTime(), period );
}
```

I want the thread to run at 00:05 am daily. However I noticed that the thread starts with a unspecified delay of 8 secs.

Am I missing something in the code? Or is there a issue with TimerTask?

There is no delay within the DailyProcess.

Comment: Where are you obtaining your delta from? Do you have timing print outs in your program?

Comment: Yes I can see the delay of 8 seconds from my logs.

Comment: `TimerTask` does not promise precise execution time. In fact, documentation is quite explicit about it.  If you need precision, I suggest using Quartz framework -> http://quartz-scheduler.org/.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that something else is running before this task, delaying the initial execution of the DailyProcess.

**According to the TimerTask documentation**:

*Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to 
execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.*

Comment: DailyProcess is the only thread that gets executed by this timer object. There is no other TimerTask either before or after.

Comment: Read the documentation on TimerTask carefully.  While the system tries to run the task at the appointed time, there is no guarantees that it will run exactly when you specify, and there are several factors that can cause some drift.  If an 8 second offset on a daily task is unacceptable for your task, then you probably can't rely on TimerTask.

Comment: A delay of 8 seconds is acceptable to me. Thanks for the clarification.